# How do I iterate through each date between two defined dates in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two dates, the begins_at (datetime) and the ends_at (datetime). I now simply want to iterate through every date between these two (including the ends_ and begins_at dates).

```
begins_at = Date.strptime("12/10/2014", "%m/%d/%Y")
ends_at = Date.strptime("12/20/2014", "%m/%d/%Y")

//iterate through all dates in this range kind of like this:

range = DateRange(begins-at,ends-at)

range.DateTime.each do |date|
    ....
end
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Range`:

```
(begins_at..ends_at).each do |date|
  # ...
end
```